# pathFor not working in Slim Framework 3

Tags: slim

In Slim 3 I have a route with a named path

```
$app->get('/admin/edit-course/{id}', '\AdminController:edit_course')->setName('/admin/edit-course');
```

If I try and access this using the router object in my templates like so...

```
var_dump($router->pathFor('/admin/edit-course'));
```

... I get an application error:

Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:

Type: InvalidArgumentException

Message: Missing data for URL segment: id

Why is this? All I want is for the router to output the URL to the `AdminController:edit_course` function. It works for my other routes, but these do not have parameters, such as ID's, being passed into the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because in get route you defined "/admin/edit-course/{id}"

so it is looking for id and its not able to get it.

```
pathFor('<< route name >>', ['id' => 0]);
```

this is the syntax so you need to pass id.

if you don't want to pass id then you need to add another route without params

```
$app->get('/admin/edit-course', '\AdminController:edit_course')
->setName('/admin/edit-course');
```